# AngularJs multiple ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have tried to do the following:

```
<accordion-heading ng-click="doSomething(); isopen=!isopen">
```

Should this work? or is it not possible to string there call together?

```
ng-click="doThis(param); doThat(param);"
```

I just need pointed in the right direction :-)

EDIT:

this:

```
ng-click="doThis(param); doThat(param);"
```

works as expected, I think it is:

```
isopen=!isopen
```

that is causing the problem, I realise I didn't say this initially.

I go around this by adding an extra div into the accordion heading, like this:

```
<accordion-heading ng-click="isopen=!isopen">
    <div ng-click="showMainView()">
        <i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': isopen, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !isopen}"></i>
        {{item.model}}<br>{{item.model_engine}}
    </div>
</accordion-heading>
```

Answer (score 3):

possible !! possible !! possible !! possible !! possible

> You can call multiple functions with ';'

See here

[Using ng-click to call two different functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584432/using-ng-click-to-call-two-different-functions)

[How to add many functions in ONE ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813945/how-to-add-many-functions-in-one-ng-click)

[How to use ng-click with multiple expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914344/how-to-use-ng-click-with-multiple-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

It works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fwSdBT3NIBrlk80aTgaB?p=preview

However be careful not to do too much logic in there. You should put the logic in the controller and only call it from the view. (isopen = !open for example doesn't belong on the view)